# Fit a fixed effect model with lm() in R without individual intercepts

Tags: r, lm, panel-data

I am working on panel regression and decided to switch to `lm()`, because `plm()` does not have a good `predict()` function for test data (as well as `linearmodels` in Python) and `lme4` syntax is not intuitive for me as a newbie to econometrics.

I want to use `lm` and predict on unseen data.

My `lm()` equation looks like this with author as a fixed effect

```
fit <- lm(y ~ a + b + factor(author), data = train)
```

Obviously it prints me thousands of individual coefficients. How to construct a model in `lm()`, evaluating for all authors without printing individually?

Comment: P.S. Appreciate any great tutorials in R/Python on predicting panel model on test data and syntax. Obviously did a ton of research in advance.

Comment: It is obvious that your shown code does not print anything. Please clarify question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume some concrete data example, e.g.

```
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- runif(100)

train <- data.frame(a, b, 
                    author = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, 1),
                    y = 3*a + .5*b + rnorm(100))
```

Now we do a fixed effect regression, I assume we do not want any Intercept so the command is

```
fit <- lm(y ~ a + b + author - 1, data = train)
```

The `- 1` part in the formula leaves the Intercpet out, instead a fixed effect is computed for each `author`. No base level left out.

Printing this model or it's summary is feasible with the 10 authors in the example but not with thousands in your work.

You can print the coefficents of only `a` and `b` like this

```
> fit$coefficients[c('a', 'b')]
         a          b 
3.02022335 0.09789947
```

You can see the coefficients and their p-values via the `anova` command

```
> anova(fit)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq   F value    Pr(>F)    
a          1 1139.90 1139.90 1034.2307 < 2.2e-16 ***
b          1    7.73    7.73    7.0127  0.009591 ** 
author    10   10.75    1.07    0.9751  0.470812    
Residuals 88   96.99    1.10
```

And you can even deconstruct `summary(fit)` for the coefficents or to display the adjusted R²:

```
> summary(fit)$coefficients[c("a", "b"),]
    Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
a 3.02022335 0.09697699 31.1437123 2.679195e-49
b 0.09789947 0.35161039  0.2784317 7.813342e-01
>
> summary(fit)$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.9122033
```

For other values see `help(summary.lm)`. Should you still want to see the coefficient of author `F` that is

```
> fit$coefficients["authorF"]
  authorF 
0.6174314
```